# 3 Flexible divs inside a flexible parent div

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I am trying to get  3 flexible images to line up horizontally and stay within the confines of their flexible div container which has a flexible background,

the background of the container and the 3 images should all stay in relation to each other positionally so they are always on top of each other.  they should get larger and smaller with the size of the browser window but not exceed 800 px in width.

The problem I am having is the background and footer slam to the left and the button divs go right.

[My JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/trapline/ZBJPF/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="footer">
    <div id="left">
        <input type="image" name="MyLeftButton" id="MyLeftButton" class="imgstretch" src="Images/MyLeftImage.png" style="border-width:0px;">
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        <input type="image" name="MyMiddleButton" id="MyMiddleButton" class="imgstretch" src="Images/MyMiddleImage.png" style="border-width:0px;">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <input type="image" name="MyRightButton" id="MyRightButton" class="imgstretch" src="Images/MyRightImage.png" style="border-width:0px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
margin: 0em auto 0em auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 800px;
}

#footer {
width: 100%;
max-width: 800px;
max-height: 80px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0em;
background-color: #009FC1;
}

#left {
float: left;
max-height: 80px;
max-width: 294px;
width: 36%;
margin-left: 20px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#middle {
max-height: 80px;
width: 25%;
float: left;
max-width: 202px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #889FC1;
}

#right {
max-height: 80px;
max-width: 294px;
width: 36%;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #9999DD;
}

.imgstretch {
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: CSS questions require the *generated* HTML, ASP template code is useless to us.

Comment: I sorry about that.  I have clarified my code and included JSFIDDLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of things going on.

1) Footer is set to fixed position, which makes it ignore the parent element and fix itself to the window.  I don't know if this is an issue for your layout, but something to note.

2) You have inline styles set on elements that you already have a defined class for.  Seems unnecessary.

3) Your dimension calculations are WAY off in relation to your % and px.  36% should be (0.36 * 800) which would come out as 288px, not 294px, and THEN plus a 20px margin.

I've forked your fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/ZBJPF/8/

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 780px;
    max-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #009FC1;
}
.footer-element-lg {
    float: left;
    width: 36%;
    max-width: 280px; 
    position: relative;
}
.footer-element-sm {
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    max-width: 220px;
    position: relative;
}
#left {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
#middle {
    background-color: #889FC1;
}
#right {
    background-color: #9999DD;
}
.imgstretch {
    width:100%;
    border: none;
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="left" class="footer-element-lg">
            <input type="image" name="MyLeftButton" id="MyLeftButton" class="imgstretch" src="Images/MyLeftImage.png">
        </div>
        <div id="middle" class="footer-element-sm">
            <input type="image" name="MyMiddleButton" id="MyMiddleButton" class="imgstretch" src="Images/MyMiddleImage.png">
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="footer-element-lg">
            <input type="image" name="MyRightButton" id="MyRightButton" class="imgstretch" src="Images/MyRightImage.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I removed a 20px margin and made the spacing as a 20px padding for continuity sake.

Comment: Thank You.  I had a hard time because the dimensions of the images didn't slice up into correct percentages and I need the footer to be stuck to the bottom of the window at all times.  I will try this in just a few minutes.

Comment: You could try adding this technique to those elements for a full stretch background.  http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ The article illustrates the example with full page BG, but it applies to any element to want to set it up with.

Comment: Hmm i tried the code above and its doing the same thing.  If it helps my original Image dimensions are

Comment: Hmm i tried the code above and its doing the same thing.  If it helps my original Image dimensions are Background=800x91,  LeftImage=294x82, Middleimage 202x82, Rightimage 294x82.   Right now the text take 100% of the width but the footer background only takes up like 60%

Comment: I changed the background image to be 721x82 so they are the same height but it still doesnt go 100% and the right hand box wraps when i shrink the browser window

Comment: ok i think im getting close :)  i changed the background to be 800x80 and all the images to the same widths with a height of 80 (the actual image size).  and i implemented the changes you suggested and it looks like the footer background needs to go over a few pixels to the right

Comment: It's not going to go 100% of the width, because the it's only 721px wide.  And you mean the BG img to what? The #footer?  Please use jQuery to show your code.

Comment: I am sorry i dotn know how to use jquery to show my code.  Its hard to describe without being able to show an image but the bg image doesnt take up 100% of the width of #footer and is aligned to the left of #footer but the 3 divs/images to take up 100% of the width.  so either the bg image and #footer needs to get taller so it can take 100% of the width (while images stay same size). or the bg image needs to be centered.

Comment: Ok thanks so much I figured it out and posted the solution here http://jsfiddle.net/ZBJPF/9/

Comment: Sorry, I meant jsFiddle not jQuery.  Glad you got it sorted.  Don't forget to accept answer.